# Hide STRICT errors on PHP 5.4

Tags: php, php5, php.ini

I've upgraded from PHP 5.3 to PHP 5.4 today. Now my script is displaying a lot of error messages. How to hide them without using `error_reporting(0);` inside php file ?

I use this:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT
```

Comment: What type of errors is it showing, that will help us know what reporting settings will hide them.  As a side note, you should probably have error logging enabled, and display of errors totally disabled.

Comment: Strict Standards: Non-static method Flyspray::absoluteURI() should not be called statically in /home/admin/prace.jobs.pl/includes/constants.inc.php on line 30

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PHP 5.4 E_STRICT became part of E_ALL - ([documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)).  My recommendation would be to turn the directive to display errors to off, and to log errors instead, this would be done by setting the following in your php.ini:

```
display_errors = off
log_errors = on
error_log = /path/to/logs/php_error.log
```

If you do not want to go down this route and still wish to display errors and simply emulate the PHP <5.4 functionality you would be best off doing something like this:

```
error_reporting = E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE
```

It should also be mentioned that various people have reported the inability to exclude E_STRICT from E_ALL in such a way as you have tried as a bug, so this might change in a later release to allow for the functionality you are used to.

Comment: It doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
error_reporting = (E_ALL ^ E_STRICT)
```

could this help?

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault - this is a ***VERY*** old question - if you are going to provide an answer to something this old please take the time to compose an *excellent* answer (providing a solution and an in-depth explanation of ***WHY*** your solution works). Just providing a line for someone to drop into a configuration file is not generally what we're looking for in an answer.  Thanks :-)

Answer (score -1):

Regular methods are meant to be called from an INSTANCE of a class (Object).

Like this: 
$object = new Class();
$object->function();

However you are calling it straight from the class.

Like this:
class::function();

Here is what STATIC methods are for.

change this:
public function absoluteURI()

To this:
public static function absoluteURI()

I recommend you always code stricly, so NOT turn off the strict errors. Why?
Your example proves it. You were using a regular method to do something it shouldn't do.

So instead of of turning off the strict errors, make these easy minor fixes to your code :)
It's worth it, i promise.

A good programmer is always open to neater coding, and will take the time to learn it.